# How to deal with Error: invalid dependent variable, non-integer values in Zero-Inflated model

Tags: r, model, zip, zero

I have a count data set with lots of 0
[image: Zero-inflated data set]

The dataset contains responds(which is the count data) and also three factors:temperature, food type, food concentration.

The data like:

```
foodtype    quantity    temperature count
Food3   Low     27  4
Food1   Medium  13  1
Food3   Medium  20  11
Food3   Medium  13  5
Food1   High    27  0
Food3   Medium  27  0
Food1   Low     20  0
Food1   Low     20  5
Food3   High    13  11
Food3   Medium  20  10
Food1   Medium  20  10
Food1   High    20  14
Food1   Medium  20  14
Food3   High    13  14
Food3   Low     20  3
Food1   High    27  6
Food3   High    27  9
Food2   Medium  20  21
Food2   High    20  24
Food1   Low     13  0
Food3   Low     13  0
Food3   High    20  19
```

I'm doing the Zero-Inflated Models with codes:

```
library(pscl)
mol<-zeroinfl(count~foodtype*quantity*temperature | count~foodtype*quantity*temperature,
    dist="poisson", link="logit", data=mydata)
```

And the Erro shows:

```
Error in zeroinfl(count~foodtype*quantity*temperature | count~foodtype*quantity*temperature  : 
  invalid dependent variable, non-integer values
```

Any ideas how to deal with the problem?
Comments and solutions are high preciated!
Thank you!

Comment: I run into the same error and in my case it had to do with the formatting of the numerical data which need to be formatted as integers (meaning 50 instead of 50.0). However, I don't see the same problem in the data that you posted, but I am not sure if this is an exact copy of the data that is in your dataset